# How to add text over and image that is a link in HTML

Tags: html

I was wondering if anybody knew a way where you can have an image that also serves as a link and then be able to put text over this image using only HTML?

Essentially what I am using this for is to create "pretty" looking buttons for my client. Unfortunately, the program that I am REQUIRED to use will not allow me to insert any CSS code so this will have to be purely HTML.

And I know I could create the image in Photo Shop with the text over it already. However, I would like this to be a dynamic button as I have hundreds that I want to format to this style and if new ones appear I don't want to create a new image every time they want a new button.

Are there any solutions to an issue like this?

Comment: What do you mean you can't use any CSS? As in, no inline styles or anything at all? What program are you required to use? This doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Yes this is correct I can't even add inline statements. And it is not that the program can't handle CSS it is that I do not have permission nor am I able to get permission to use CSS in my code. Every time I add an inline statement when the code is saved that portion is automatically deleted. It is a giant pain, which is why I was wondering if there was a HTML workaround that somebody knew of.

Comment: Can you provide us the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though I still can't for the life of me understand why you would want to do something like this. Or why someone would care about restricting css markup since it's not even really code. However you could take it back to the old school HTML4 days and do something like this if I understand your restrictions correctly. Which should still render fine in html5. Hope it helps.

[CODEPEN TO PLAY](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MyowzW)

...PS, tell whoever decided to restrict CSS use that it's pretty counter intuitive to a contemporary...well, anything. Just my two cents. :D

Oh also, by the way, elements like `<center>` aren't supported in html5 even though it should render, so you'd be breaking some rules. If they mean for it to be an actual HTML5 solution, then you require CSS.

```html
<table>  
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td rowspan=2><img src="http://res.freestockphotos.biz/pictures/15/15789-illustration-of-a-blank-glossy-rectangular-button-pv.png" 
                       height="50" width="200">
    </td>
  </tr>  
  <tr>
    <td colspan=2><center>overlay text</center></td>
  </tr>  
</table>
```

You could also just use like `background=` on a `td` or something if your images are all fixed size etc.

Comment: Gald you got a remedy. Though you can tell your restrictive overlords I called them weenies for limiting your CSS ability lol. Have a great weekend. :)

Comment: lol I completely agree this has been a huge hindrance on my abilities and yet they still expect the same results. Go figure...